# Query Database using WF 4.0 Activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I am trying to create few generic activities to select/update/insert records in database.

Is it advisable to do such database operations from WF activities ? Or should I abstract these operations in a WCF service and consume it from the WF ?

Only reason I want to avoid creating a WCF service is that the WF/queries involved are fairly simple. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem doing database queries from your activities. In fact the WF team has create an WF ADO.NET Activity Pack on [CodePlex](http://wf.codeplex.com/releases/view/43585) that does just that.